# Proper xpath Syntax for Extracting Two Text Values

Tags: xpath

I am trying to scrape a web page for NAME OF COMPANY and CITY AND STATE OF COMPANY shown below.

I have an xpath code snippet that identifies both text elements at the same time:

```
// span[starts-with(@class,"text-align")]/text()[2]
```

This xpath snippet pulls the first text value (COMPANY NAME).  How do I get the second text element (CITY,STATE)?

A snip of the web page code looks like this:

```
<div>
        <ul class="pv-top-card-v3--experience-list">
            <li>
              <a class="pv-top-card-v3--experience-list-item" href="#" data-control-name="position_see_more" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-172="172">
                <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQFhA8h46hvabA/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1582761600&amp;v=beta&amp;t=VAeZqaGu3Lu6Ol_n5kiiI74FSRuSOZA1ggAI5qTVRjE" id="ember173" class="EntityPhoto-square-1 flex-shrink-zero ember-view">

                <span id="ember174" class="text-align-left ml2 t-14 t-black t-bold full-width lt-line-clamp lt-line-clamp--multi-line ember-view" style="-webkit-line-clamp: 2">  THIS IS THE NAME OF A COMPANY

<!----></span>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class="pv-top-card-v3--experience-list-item" href="#" data-control-name="education_see_more" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-176="176">
                <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEr2uQX-x2EwQ/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1582761600&amp;v=beta&amp;t=aDbYLUDMvlS4DpwOLjOaQj3Dj60C_cYLC5UUvGoyld0" id="ember177" class="EntityPhoto-square-1 flex-shrink-zero ember-view">

                <span id="ember178" class="text-align-left ml2 t-14 t-black t-bold full-width lt-line-clamp lt-line-clamp--multi-line ember-view" style="-webkit-line-clamp: 2">  THIS IS THE CITY AND STATE OF COMPANY

<!----></span>
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The xpath string is picking up the two `span` elements using `class`.  I can't use the `span id` attributes because they are dynamic and change with each page (one page per company).

Can someone advise how I extract the desired text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

point to the `li` level.

```
//ul/li[2]/a/span[starts-with(@class,"text-align")]
```